# Upgrade Grails 2.1.3 -> 2.2.0 fails when using inline plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, upgrade

we have an application in which a inline plugin is used. This is defined in the BuildConfig using.

```
grails.plugin.location."foo-shared" = "../../foo-shared/src"
```

Now when we try to upgrade our application from Grails 2.1.3 to 2.2.0 it seems that the inline plugin classes are not found in our main application.

Any suggestion what i am missing?

/Marco

Comment: Can you list the contents of that src folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you move "grails.plugin.location" outside of "grails.project.dependency.resolution" it works.

[Jira ticket](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9735)

Comment: I have trouble imagining how it could ever have worked _inside_ the dependency resolution closure in the first place...

Comment: grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
    }
    repositories {...
    }
    dependencies {...
    }
    plugins {...
    }
}
grails.plugin.location.'userInterface' = "../user-interface"

Comment: put the inline plugin definition outside of plugins definition and also outside of grails.project.dependency.resolution